# javascript for repeats in object

Tags: javascript, object

hey guys I have a problem :)

the result is wrong.I am filtering for personnal codes and dates. every personal has an array for it. You can see it from dateArr. in dateArr you can see 2 different arrays. these are two different personal actually.  In vm.resReport there is dates for these personels I want to took the values of personnel that in vm.resREport and personnel code of it equal to dateArr's personnel. And put these values to dateArr

```
for(var item in vm.resReport){
    for(var k=0;k < Object.keys(vm.dateArr).length;k++){
        for(var days in vm.dateArr[k].Days){
            if(vm.resReport[item].mDate==vm.dateArr[k].Days[days].FullDate){
                for(var per in vm.resReport[item].Details){
                    if(vm.dateArr[k].PersonnelCode==vm.resReport[item].Details[per].PersonnelCode){
                        console.log(vm.resReport[item].Details[per].PersonnelFirstName);
                        vm.dateArr[k].Days[days].PersonnelCode=[];
                        vm.dateArr[k].Days[days].PersonnelCode[vm.dateArr[k].PersonnelCode]=vm.resReport[item].Details[per].PersonnelCode;
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

my problem is, in the second repeat. The for circle works actually but it repeats all together for whatever the k. but it needs to finilise the first k element than the other. but it just repeats all together.

How can I solve this? Thank you :) Cheers!

Edit: Here my Object

```
    {
0:{Days:Array[30],PersonnelCode:"PRS_001" PersonnelFirstName:"Güvenc" PersonnelLastName:"Vural"},
1:{Days:Array[30],PersonnelCode:"PRS_111" PersonnelFirstName:"Timur" PersonnelLastName:"Hacizade"}
}
```

here my resReport Object;

```
[
  {
    "Total": 1,
    "mDate": "2016-02-15",
    "Details": [
      {
        "PersonnelFirstName": "Güvenc",
        "PersonnelLastName": "Vural",
        "PersonnelCode": "PRS_001",
        "Total": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Total": 1,
    "mDate": "2016-03-08",
    "Details": [
      {
        "PersonnelFirstName": "Güvenc",
        "PersonnelLastName": "Vural",
        "PersonnelCode": "PRS_001",
        "Total": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Total": 1,
    "mDate": "2016-04-08",
    "Details": [
      {
        "PersonnelFirstName": "Güvenc",
        "PersonnelLastName": "Vural",
        "PersonnelCode": "PRS_001",
        "Total": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Total": 3,
    "mDate": "2016-04-09",
    "Details": [
      {
        "PersonnelFirstName": "Güvenc",
        "PersonnelLastName": "Vural",
        "PersonnelCode": "PRS_001",
        "Total": 2
      },
      {
        "PersonnelFirstName": "Timur",
        "PersonnelLastName": "Hacizade",
        "PersonnelCode": "PRS_111",
        "Total": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Total": 1,
    "mDate": "2016-04-13",
    "Details": [
      {
        "PersonnelFirstName": "Güvenc",
        "PersonnelLastName": "Vural",
        "PersonnelCode": "PRS_001",
        "Total": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Total": 1,
    "mDate": "2016-04-14",
    "Details": [
      {
        "PersonnelFirstName": "Güvenc",
        "PersonnelLastName": "Vural",
        "PersonnelCode": "PRS_001",
        "Total": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and here my dateArr Object

```
[
  {
    "PersonnelCode": "PRS_001",
    "PersonnelFirstName": "Güvenc",
    "PersonnelLastName": "Vural",
    "Days": [
      {
        "Day": "01",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-01",
        "ID": 92,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": "02",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-02",
        "ID": 93,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": "03",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-03",
        "ID": 94,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": "04",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-04",
        "ID": 95,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": "05",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-05",
        "ID": 96,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": "06",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-06",
        "ID": 97,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": "07",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-07",
        "ID": 98,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": "08",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-08",
        "ID": 99,
        "StatusName": 1,
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false,
        "Details": [
          {
            "PersonnelFirstName": "Güvenc",
            "PersonnelLastName": "Vural",
            "PersonnelCode": "PRS_001",
            "Total": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Day": "09",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-09",
        "ID": 100,
        "StatusName": 3,
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false,
        "Details": [
          {
            "PersonnelFirstName": "Güvenc",
            "PersonnelLastName": "Vural",
            "PersonnelCode": "PRS_001",
            "Total": 2
          },
          {
            "PersonnelFirstName": "Timur",
            "PersonnelLastName": "Hacizade",
            "PersonnelCode": "PRS_111",
            "Total": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Day": 10,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-10",
        "ID": 101,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 11,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-11",
        "ID": 102,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 12,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-12",
        "ID": 103,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 13,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-13",
        "ID": 104,
        "StatusName": 1,
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false,
        "Details": [
          {
            "PersonnelFirstName": "Güvenc",
            "PersonnelLastName": "Vural",
            "PersonnelCode": "PRS_001",
            "Total": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Day": 14,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-14",
        "ID": 105,
        "StatusName": 1,
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false,
        "Details": [
          {
            "PersonnelFirstName": "Güvenc",
            "PersonnelLastName": "Vural",
            "PersonnelCode": "PRS_001",
            "Total": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Day": 15,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-15",
        "ID": 106,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 16,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-16",
        "ID": 107,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 17,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-17",
        "ID": 108,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 18,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-18",
        "ID": 109,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 19,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-19",
        "ID": 110,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 20,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-20",
        "ID": 111,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 21,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-21",
        "ID": 112,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 22,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-22",
        "ID": 113,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 23,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-23",
        "ID": 114,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 24,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-24",
        "ID": 115,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 25,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-25",
        "ID": 116,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 26,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-26",
        "ID": 117,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 27,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-27",
        "ID": 118,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 28,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-28",
        "ID": 119,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 29,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-29",
        "ID": 120,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 30,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-30",
        "ID": 121,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      }
    ],
    "Update": false
  },
  {
    "PersonnelCode": "PRS_111",
    "PersonnelFirstName": "Timur",
    "PersonnelLastName": "Hacizade",
    "Days": [
      {
        "Day": "01",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-01",
        "ID": 92,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": "02",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-02",
        "ID": 93,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": "03",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-03",
        "ID": 94,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": "04",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-04",
        "ID": 95,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": "05",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-05",
        "ID": 96,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": "06",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-06",
        "ID": 97,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": "07",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-07",
        "ID": 98,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": "08",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-08",
        "ID": 99,
        "StatusName": 1,
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false,
        "Details": [
          {
            "PersonnelFirstName": "Güvenc",
            "PersonnelLastName": "Vural",
            "PersonnelCode": "PRS_001",
            "Total": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Day": "09",
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-09",
        "ID": 100,
        "StatusName": 3,
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false,
        "Details": [
          {
            "PersonnelFirstName": "Güvenc",
            "PersonnelLastName": "Vural",
            "PersonnelCode": "PRS_001",
            "Total": 2
          },
          {
            "PersonnelFirstName": "Timur",
            "PersonnelLastName": "Hacizade",
            "PersonnelCode": "PRS_111",
            "Total": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Day": 10,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-10",
        "ID": 101,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 11,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-11",
        "ID": 102,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 12,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-12",
        "ID": 103,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 13,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-13",
        "ID": 104,
        "StatusName": 1,
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false,
        "Details": [
          {
            "PersonnelFirstName": "Güvenc",
            "PersonnelLastName": "Vural",
            "PersonnelCode": "PRS_001",
            "Total": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Day": 14,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-14",
        "ID": 105,
        "StatusName": 1,
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false,
        "Details": [
          {
            "PersonnelFirstName": "Güvenc",
            "PersonnelLastName": "Vural",
            "PersonnelCode": "PRS_001",
            "Total": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Day": 15,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-15",
        "ID": 106,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 16,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-16",
        "ID": 107,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 17,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-17",
        "ID": 108,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 18,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-18",
        "ID": 109,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 19,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-19",
        "ID": 110,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 20,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-20",
        "ID": 111,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 21,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-21",
        "ID": 112,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 22,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-22",
        "ID": 113,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 23,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-23",
        "ID": 114,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 24,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-24",
        "ID": 115,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 25,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-25",
        "ID": 116,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 26,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-26",
        "ID": 117,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 27,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-27",
        "ID": 118,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 28,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-28",
        "ID": 119,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 29,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-29",
        "ID": 120,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      },
      {
        "Day": 30,
        "Cls": "",
        "ClsStatus": "",
        "FullDate": "2016-04-30",
        "ID": 121,
        "StatusName": "NA",
        "Popover": false,
        "Update": false
      }
    ],
    "Update": false
  }
]
```

Comment: Why are you using `Object.keys(vm.dateArr).length` instead of `vm.dateArr.length`?

Comment: it is an object you are right but it didnt solve the problem :/ any other ideas?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do here. Can you show the original values and what you're trying to get as a result?

Comment: If it's an object why are you accessing it like an array, instead of using the keys? `vm.dateArr[k]` should be `vm.dateArr[Object.keys(vm.dateArr)[k]]`.

Comment: oh sorry :D in my object my keys are like 0 , 1 ,2, 3... like this.

Comment: Then why don't you make it a real array instead of an object? Anyway, that's probably not relevant to your question. Show the data so we can understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: {0:{Days:Array[30],PersonnelCode:"PRS_001"
PersonnelFirstName:"Güvenc"
PersonnelLastName:"Vural"},1:{Days:Array[30],PersonnelCode:"PRS_111"
PersonnelFirstName:"Timur"
PersonnelLastName:"Hacizade"}}

Comment: That's unreadable. Put it in the question, so you can format it readably.

Comment: I edited it :) Can you look it again? and thank you so much for all

Comment: Where are `resReport` and `dateArr` in that object? What is the result you're trying to get from it?

Comment: it is an another object and comes from api service

Comment: We need to see all the input and the desired result to understand the question.

Comment: I put all my object on edit Thank you so much. I thought it was clear but now I see it was not. Hope it is more readable now.

Comment: You still haven't said what you're trying to do with the objects. We can't figure it out from the code, because it doesn't do what you want!

Comment: in this for;
for(var days in vm.dateArr[k].Days

I want to work with inner repeat, for k in-order. But it runs the inner repeat for k equal 0 than 1 than the upper for is finishes and it repats all these steps again. I want to work with k equal 0's first than k equal 1's

Comment: I still don't understand. Don't tell us how you're trying to do it, tell us what it's trying to do. And put it in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it sounds like you just need to put the `item` loop inside the `k` loop, instead of the `k` loop inside the `item` loop.

Comment: OMG! you are right :D OW thank you so much barmar. If you write it as an answer I will verify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the `k = 0` done before all the `k = 1`, and so on, you need to invert the nesting of the loops.

```
for(var k=0;k < Object.keys(vm.dateArr).length;k++){
    for(var item in vm.resReport){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the solution and tell me if it solved the problem.

```
for(var item in vm.resReport){
    var report = vm.resReport[item];
    for(var k=0;k < Object.keys(vm.dateArr).length;k++){
        var dateInfo = vm.dateArr[k];
        var days = dateInfo.Days;
        for(var day in days){
            var currDay = days[day];
            if(report.mDate==currDay.FullDate){
                for(var per in report.Details){
                    var detail = report.Details[per];
                    if(dateInfo.PersonnelCode==detail.PersonnelCode){
                        console.log(detail.PersonnelFirstName);
                        currDay.PersonnelCode=[];
                        currDay.PersonnelCode[dateInfo.PersonnelCode]=detail.PersonnelCode;
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you it helped but still it doesnt work :/ I updated my question and it is more readable now. can you look it again? thank you :)

Comment: Can you give me also the resReport?

Comment: I add resReport and dateArr objects to my edit. you can look :) Thank you again.

Comment: Now please check to see if this works

Comment: I see that now you changed dateArr to array is that correct?

Comment: Ok please check this one.

Comment: Then please set this as the answer. ;)

Comment: Ok it seems that you chose another one. ;) Ok